# Dynamically add DIV element with varying values

Tags: javascript

I would like to create a div card dynamically with varying values depending on the result of my API. Currently, values keep overriding each other because they all share the same element ID. Is there a way for me to dynamically add all the values into their own cards?

```
res.forEach(x => {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.className = "card mb-4 box-shadow";
    div.innerHTML = `
        <div class="card-header">
           <h4 id="serverName" class="my-0 font-weight-normal"></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
           <h1 id="serverPrice" class="card-title pricing-card-title"></h1>
           <p id="serverTraits" class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4"></p>
        </div>`

        document.getElementById("content").appendChild(div);
        document.getElementById("serverName").innerHTML = x.name
        document.getElementById("serverPrice").innerHTML = x.price + '$'
        document.getElementById("serverTraits").innerHTML = x.traits
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way that works with your current solution is to simply append the index or a number behind your ids

e.g

```
<!-- your html code becomes something like this -->
<h4 id="serverName1" class="my-0 font-weight-normal"></h4>
<h4 id="serverName2" class="my-0 font-weight-normal"></h4>
<h4 id="serverName3" class="my-0 font-weight-normal"></h4>
```

When retrieving, likewise, append the index

```
document.getElementById("serverName" + index).innerHTML = x.name
```

This way, all your ids will be unique.

EDIT:
The following is an example of how you can append a number behind your id

```
innerHTML = `
    <div class="card-header">
       <h4 id="serverName` + 1 + `" class="my-0 font-weight-normal"></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
       <h1 id="serverPrice" class="card-title pricing-card-title"></h1>
       <p id="serverTraits" class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4"></p>
    </div>`;
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the innerHTML I initially set has the ID name set to serverName & such. How can I append the index to the innerHTML in `div.innerHTML`

Comment: In javascript, when handling strings, you can use the + operator to concatenate strings e.g join a number and a string together. I updated my answer with an example of how you can add a number behind the 'serverName' inside your div.innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

Why do not generate the content dynamically before appending it to the "content" element?

Simple! no ...?

look at this

```
div.innerHTML = `
    <div class="card-header">
       <h4 id="serverName" class="my-0 font-weight-normal">${x.name}</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
       <h1 id="serverPrice" class="card-title pricing-card-title">${x.price}</h1>
       <p id="serverTraits" class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">${x.traits}</p>
    </div>`
document.getElementById("content").appendChild(div);
```